# alt + arrows not working to go back/forward

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Hello I don't know what happened and when was the last time it worked but on my work laptop with Windows 10 I cannot go back in browser / Total Command / windows explorer or anything by pressing Alt+left arrow. Going forward with Alt+right arrow also does nothing. Any idea what can be wrong? I suppose it is either some other application stealing this key combination for itself or maybe some keyboard settings is wrong. It works normally on my home desktop Win 10

Comment: Se if this happens when booting in Safe Mode.

Comment: unfortunately I can't get into safe mode because it's a company laptop and it want's bitlocker recovery key when I do that...

Comment: Try then doing a [clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows).

Comment: this worked! But now I have disabled a lot of things so it's hard to say which was doing it :) I will see. I suspect called lenovo enhanced keyboard driver something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As when booting in
[clean boot mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows)
the problem does not arrive, this indicates
that some third-party application is responsible for swallowing up these keys.

To locate the problematic application, you may continue to use msconfig
or the free tool
[Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns).

You may turn off startup items in bunches and return them after a reboot if there
was no change.
Microsoft drivers should be left alone.

The Lenovo Enhanced Performance USB Keyboard does not look like a good candidate,
but everything is possible. Ensure you have the latest driver.

Answer (score 0):

Search "advanced system settings" in windows search box.

In the advanced system settings under "Advanced" tab ,click settings for performance.

In "visual effects tab check "Enable Aero peek"

Comment: So now I see desktop when I move my mouse to bottom right corner OK... But this does not have any effect on my issue. alt+arrows still do nothing. I don't understand how this can be related anyway?

Comment: If "Enable Aero peek" is unchecked,you can't use alt+arrows keys

Comment: sorry but not true. On my desktop PC the settings "Use Peek to preview the desktop when you move your mouse to she Show desktop button at the end of the taskbar" is off and alt+arrows work fine